# numpy power function output for 2 to the power 63

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I am running some test code and observed something strange. the numpy power function giving strange output post 2 to the power 62

```
p=np.array([1,2,3,50,60,62,63,70,80,99])
np.power(2,p)
```

The outout of above code is

```
array([                   2,                    4,                    8,
       1125899906842624,  1152921504606846976,  4611686018427387904,
   -9223372036854775808,                    0,                    0,
                      0])
```

[image]

Curious if someone can explain what is happening here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Numpy uses C datatype and thus it has limited precision. I guess the highest precision integer in your system is 64-bit. You can refer the documentation of [NumPy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html) to get a more detailed answer on overflow errors and extended precision.